# How to prove that $\det(A) \in \{1,-1\} \implies AA^t = A^tA = I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, orthonormal

> Prove that if $\det(A) \in \{1,-1\}$ then $AA^t = A^tA = I_n$.

I have no clue, to be fair. I am trying to prove orthogonal polynomials have a determinant $1$. Any help?

Comment: Isn't this missing some assumptions?

Comment: The determinant of any orthogonal matrix is +1 or −1. @T.Bongers

Comment: Yes, but not every matrix with determinant one is orthogonal.

Comment: But why? I have no idea. Please lead me in the right direction?

Comment: you said you want to prove orthogonal polynomials have determinant $1$ but your stated question is if $\det (A)=\pm 1$ then $A$ is orthogonal.. do you want to prove both ways (one of which is false) :O

Comment: I thought it was both ways @PraphullaKoushik but I was just proven wrong.

Comment: Now that he gave you a counter example, what are the other assumptions?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Mhenni: I am working on a problem.

Comment: Note that, if $A$ is orthogonal, then $|A|=\pm 1$.

Comment: @Mhenni: Proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, this is false: Let $A$ be defined by

$$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac 1 2\end{array}\right)$$

Then $\det(A) = 2 \cdot \frac 1 2 - 0 = 1$, but $AA^T = A^2 \ne I_2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that $\det({\bf{M}}) = \pm 1$ implies that ${\bf MM}^{\top} = \bf{I}$. As you have seen above.

However, if ${\bf MM}^{\top} = \bf{I}$ then $\det({\bf{M}}) = \pm 1$. This follows from three simple facts:

- $\det({\bf MN}) = \det( {\bf M})\det({\bf N})$
- $\det({\bf M}^{\top}) = \det({\bf M})$
- $\det({\bf I}) = 1$

Assume that ${\bf MM}^{\top} = \bf{I}$ and take the determinant of both sides:
$$\det({\bf MM}^{\top}) = \det({\bf I})$$
$$\det({\bf M})\det({\bf M}^{\top}) = 1$$
$$\det({\bf M})\det({\bf M}) = 1$$
$$\det({\bf M})^2 = 1$$
$$\det({\bf M}) = \pm1$$